# Call row with link and Id

Tags: php, mysql, row, echo

My question is, how can you locate and echo content of a specific row using the row id in the url bar. `Example: Row 4: name: bob email: 123@abc.com` and when someone visit lets give an example: website.com/123.php?=4 (does not have to be exactly like this) it echos name: bob email: 123@abc.com. If you need to understand more please ask.

```
More of an example:
Row: 9999
name: smith
email: smith@email.com
password: smith123
```

user visits `www.website.com/?9999` or `www.website.com/123.php?=9999` (or any type of link - not the link having the row number/id thats) and then on the page it echos for example:
Thanks for visiting  page. Contact him and , thank you.
Basically I want to be able to call the information of a certain row by using its row number in the url bar.

Comment: Instead of using www.website.com/123.php?=9999, use www.website.com/123.php?rowid=9999. Then in php use $_GET['rowid'] function to get that id

Comment: Rmemeber, "rows" in a database *have no intrinsic order".  If you want to search for "id=4" ... then your table needs to have a column named "id", and one (and only one) of the rows should have a value of "4".  This is called a "primary key".  The corresponding SQL query would be something like `select * from mytable where id=4;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply with Query String :

```
www.url.com/page.php?id=121
```

get the id with $_GET

```
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{


//    fetch and display the information with      database Query 

$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons where id = " . $_GET['id']);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['name'] . " " . $row['email'];
  echo "<br>";
  }

mysqli_close($con);



}
```

Comment: You should at least cast the id to an int to guard against injection

Answer (score 1):

Use `$_GET[]` method to fetch the value from the URL and later fetch that row from the database, for example

```
www.domain.com/page.php?id=4
```

So now on `page.php` use this piece of code

```
if(!empty($_GET['id'])) {
   $id = $_GET['id']; //Don't Forget to sanitize it before using it in your query
   //Check whether id exists like
   $is_valid_id = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE id = $id");
   if(mysqli_num_rows($is_valid_id) != 1) {
      //Redirect
   }
} else {
   //Redirect or throw some error
}
```

Now use this id to fetch a row using query

```
$query = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM table_name 
                                                       WHERE id = $id"));
```

Now you can easily `echo` out the data like

```
/* Assuming first_name and last_name as column names */
echo $query['first_name']; //Bob
echo $query['last_name']; //Doe
/* And so on... */
```